# How to make Drupal links relative

Tags: xampp

Recently began exploring Drupal (and web development as a whole). After setting up Drupal on my local apache server (xampp), I've noticed that the links all refer to the root of the webserver, instead of relative to Drupal's directory (Drupal is located in a sub dir of my webserver).

I've tried searching google, but don't know exactly what to search for.

How to change this behaviour?

Comment: [Maybe this can help](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5369)

Comment: Which links are you talking about? The answer LW001 linked to above assumes you are talking about links added in fields (on a node add form for example). Have you set up your hosts file properly or are you accessing your site via `localhost` in the url? Have you tried setting the `base_url` in the settings file? Which version are you actually using? You have both Drupal 7 and Drupal 8 tagged

Comment: It seems both Drupal tags have now been removed, not helpful at all.

Comment: The drupal tags were removed because this is a problem with the hosts file and has nothing to do with Drupal

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I added the tags, let alone remove them. I'm pretty new to this site. The links I'm talking about are the hyperlinks after 'installing' Drupal. I visit the site by going to localhost/sub-dir. The hyperlink 'Admin' then tries to find that destination in the root, instead of the subdir..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set up your sites correctly in your hosts file.
There are plenty of tutorials on this.

Currently your hosts file probably redirects to your webserver, you have to set up each site you create to redirect to your drupal webroot.